# How can I modify an UIButton inside a TableViewCell from a TableSource?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

### What I need

I have a UITableView, and each of its cells have a CustomCheckBox (which is a UIButton) and a label. I want that, when I click the Row (the RowSelected method), the Selected property of said UIButton changes and therefore changes the Image of the clicked UIButton.

I have a CustomCheckBox.cs

```
public partial class CustomCheckBox : UIButton
{
    public CustomCheckBox(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("ic_check_on"), UIControlState.Selected);
        this.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("ic_check_off"), UIControlState.Normal);
        this.TouchUpInside += (s, args) =>
        {
            this.Selected = !this.Selected;
        };
    }
}
```

An ItemCellView.cs

```
public partial class ItemCellView : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("ItemCellView");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    static ItemCCellView()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName("ItemCellView", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    public ItemCCellView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ItemCellView, ItemViewModel>();
            set.Bind(this.lblDescription).To(p => p.Description);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }
}
```

And a TableSource.cs

```
public class CoberturasOpcionalesSource : MvxTableViewSource
{
    private PlanMulticoberturaOpcional SelectedItem;
    readonly CotizarMulticoberturaViewModel ViewModel;

    private UIViewController parentView;

    public CoberturasOpcionalesSource(UITableView tableView, CotizarMulticoberturaViewModel viewModel) : base(tableView)
    {
        this.ViewModel = viewModel;
        this.UseAnimations = true;
        this.AddAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.Top;
        this.RemoveAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.Middle;
        tableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 30.0f;

        tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName(ItemCellView.Key, NSBundle.MainBundle), ItemCellView.Key);
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return this.ViewModel.ObsCollection.Count;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    protected override object GetItemAt(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return this.ViewModel.ObsCollection[indexPath.Section];
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);

        var cell = (ItemCellView)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ItemCellView.Key, indexPath);

        cell.btnCheckBox.SendActionForControlEvents(UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);

        var item = this.ViewModel.ObsCollection[indexPath.Section];
        if (item != null)
        {
            //
        }
    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        var cell = (ItemCellView)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ItemCellView.Key, indexPath);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

### The problem

I have a breakpoint on the TouchUpInsde in the CustomCheckbox.cs. When I touch the row, it stops on the TouchUpInside but it doesn't do anything

### The solution

Thanks to @Garfield81. I was creating a new cell on the RowSelected method. I change it for this:

```
var cell = (ItemCellView)tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is in the `RowSelected` method you are using `DequeResuableCell` to get a new cell instead of trying to get access to the one already displaying.

Instead you need to the use the `cellForRow` method (or it's Xamarin equivalent) to get the cell that was selected.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.